# Xerces C++ XML: escape is really hard to do?

Tags: c++, xml, xerces, xerces-c

I am using Xerces library, everything is fine to use but now I want to escape the XML string and I found there is a XMLFormatter class used for that, after I dig into the doc, I see it is really hard to use from the constructor perspective. What I want is just 2 functions:

string escape(string);

string unescape(string);

why xerces makes this so hard to do?

Comment: What do you mean by 'escape'?  Could you show an example of what you're trying to do?

Comment: http://xerces.apache.org/xerces-c/apiDocs-2/classXMLFormatter.html#748efc31a844072c83236280e145e0e8

Answer (score -1):

What you're trying to do isn't really related to the XML itself.  If you were to store the XML to a file then this wouldn't be necessary.  Ditto if you were sending over a network connection using just TPC or UDP.  I assume you want to send it over HTTP, and this is really something I would expect to see as a function of whatever library you're using to do your HTTP communication.  Do you expect to see functions to escape for MySQL, MS SQL, Oracle, JSON?

Comment: No, that's not true, what if the attribute has ' inside? That will mess up the parser, eg) <cmd attri='ab'/> <cmd attri='a'b' />